# get row value on update Button

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, telerik, entity-framework-6

[image: See This Photo Plz]

get the Product SKU Of the row which the button pressed

```
protected void On_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `DataKeyNames` property.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SKU">
```

And then you can access the correct DataKeyNames based on the Row Index.

```
protected void On_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a control and get the gridviewrow from the namingconainer
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

    //get the gridview itself from the gridviewrow
    GridView gv = row.Parent.Parent as GridView;

    //get the correct datakey from the gridview with the dataitemindex
    int SKU = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Values[0]);

    //display result
    Label1.Text = SKU.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Actually  i"m using Telerik (RadGrid)

Comment: Ah. I do not know radgrid myself. But maybe it has a similar mechanism and you can adapt my answer to that?